# .Net app installed/running in AppData folder?

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce

I have a WPF app (installed on Windows 10 machines) that relies on XML files for various data elements.

After building the app and installing it, the app and XML files are deployed to different folders, as follows:

**XML Files**
   [AppData\Local\Apps...]\vita..tion_4af4e5dd3b243aa8_0001.0000_**fa5707b5107abce1**

**EXE**
[AppData\Local\Apps...]\vita..tion_4af4e5dd3b243aa8_0001.0000_**f75ca9501de16621**

This prevents me from accessing my files using something like this:

```
    Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + "\\XML\\GeneralInfo.xml";
```

### Questions

- How can I refer to the XML files in code?
- Is this some weird artifact of a messed-up publishing?

Thanks!

#### EDIT

Using Publish Wizard (or Publish Now) to publish the app.

The XML files are marked as 
  Build Action: "Content" and 
  Copy to Output Directory: "Copy Always"
in properties.

Comment: Are you using Publish Wizard to create a ClickOnce application? How are you deploying your XML files?

Comment: @appayipyip -- Just updated the question; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is <s>normal behavior</s> *not a result of some weird artifact of a messed-up publishing*¹.

Try access your files using this:

```
var deployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

var pathToXml = Path.Combine(deployment.DataDirectory, "MyFile.xml");
```

You will have to add a reference to `System.Deployment` on your application.

Hope that helps :)

-

¹ From an answer by Chester Hong on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6e3d328-1deb-49c9-99cf-98fe3830702a/where-does-clickonce-put-files?forum=winformssetup) question:

> Each ClickOnce application is installed in per-user, per-application cache folder. You can find the folder like:
>
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0
>
> You can go to Publish tab and click Application Files button. **The files whose Publish Status are Data File will be installed into data folder**, which you can specify by `CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory` property.

(Few parts ommited, adjusted and highlited by me)